# How to ignore comments in the LaTeX file with ispell (within Emacs if possible)

Tags: emacs, latex, spell-checking, ispell

I'm writing a text with Latex in English but written my comments in Finnish. When I'm running the spell checking with ispell, I got to run through all the comments. Is there a handy way to skip the comments with the ispell? If that could be done with emacs, that would be double handy =)

One way would be to run the ispell within console and process the input with sed, for example, but I'd like to have my changes straight on the file...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(setq ispell-check-comments nil)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to dig in the code a bit, but when you spell-check a file, it's running the detex tool to strip out the TeX code.  You should be able to modify the pipeline to have a sed or perl script strip the comment lines.

I kind of vaguely think AuC-TeX makes this configurable, but 30 seconds looking didn't reveal it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a modern answer to this old question, because I also had the problem:
**Just use aspell, which does this out of the box**.